# How can I trigger a bash command every time someone fails to login?

Tags: bash, login

I'd like to take a picture from the webcam every time someone tries to login into the system. I know I can do that with:

```
mplayer -vo png -frames 1 tv://
```

How can I trigger this command when someone fails to login?

Comment: Do users log in using X/Wayland login manager, via ssh, or via tty?

Comment: X/Wayland login manager primarily.

Comment: I don't know the answer right away but I've looked into gdm source
code and I think that you can play around with PAM and PostLogin
script to set up some kind of callback at login time and remove it
after user successfully logged-in.  Also look in `do_authenticate()`
and `g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error()` run if authentication
fails. I'm afraid that the answer for this question will depend on
what login manager you use.  You can also modify your preferred login
manager's source code of course but it can get hard to maintain.

Comment: It also depends on what OS you use as `PAM` might not be yet available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Failed logins are registered by `lastb` if the `/var/log/wtmp`  exits.
You can monitor changes to this file, `/var/log/wtmp`, with `inotify-tools`
You can  get the output with `last` or `lastb`
If you notice some failed login message, you'll know when it happens, and you can create a condition to trigger the command you wish.

In more detail:

For monitoring the file, this is triggered when it changes:
`while inotifywait -e close_write /var/log/wtmp; do <myscrip>.sh; done`

`lastb | grep -q "failed login"` will output a 0 and exit without any other output, if the string is present, which will be the case by a failed login.

You can create a conditional if-statement in Bash like this:

```
if lastb | grep -q "failed login";
then <ascript>.sh;
fi;
```

You might need to create `/var/log/wtmp`, which can be done with `touch /var/log/wtmp`

Comment: That much is clear, but how do you monitor that file?  Some shell-based `watch` perhaps?  You don't want to poll because of the delay involved.

Comment: @Ned64: updated answer with standard package for this.

Comment: Thanks.  Present a solution instead of naming building blocks and I am sure you have the OP's upvote as well as mine.

Comment: @Ned64: updated